# Setting up a triple-boot from scratch - Win7, Win8 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-8

I'm getting a replacement laptop tomorrow so I get to set it up from scratch. I want to triple-boot Win7, Win8 and Ubuntu (all 64-bit) and I can see several answers about this already, but I was wondering what the best install order is. I'm assuming it will be:

1. Windows 7
2. Windows 8
3. Ubuntu 12.10

Has anyone tried this? Any reason I should change the order?

The other option would be to run Windows 8 from a VHD (see [Scott Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx)) but now it's been released I don't see much advantage to this.

Update:
I tried this but ran into [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204395/how-do-i-use-lvm-with-12-10-when-i-already-have-windows-8) because MBR only supports a maximum of 4 primary partitions. If you're worried about this [convert the drive to GPT before installing Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-clean-install-windows-7-professional-64-bit/c052117c-8faa-4b5b-bd31-30bb9b21a0eb).

Comment: actually, mbr supports 4 *primary* partitions. You can format one as an extended, and nest as many logical partitions as needed inside it.

Comment: Fair point, but unfortunately my laptop already has 4 primary partitions: Win7, Win8, HP_TOOLS (FAT32, 5GB) and System Reserved (100MB, NTFS). I don't think I can convert any of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if it comes with Windows 7, then install Windows 8, which will update your boot loader to allow you to access both partitions. Then install Ubuntu which will create a new boot loader with the ability to select Windows 8 or Earlier version of Windows (Or something close). I did this on my EEE pc and it worked fine (except XP instead of 7, but that should work fine).

Now, a warning. NEVER, install ubuntu before Windows 8, if you install Windows 8 after Ubuntu it will change the boot loader and will only allow you to boot to Windows 7 and 8. You will have to reinstall the grub on Ubuntu in order to access it.